# Android Background Image Appears In Eclipse But Not Emulator

Tags: android, background-image

I have created a background image from my app, and adding a copy of the image to each of the drawable folders (low, med, high resolution) and then defined the code in the main.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.57" 
        android:background="@drawable/scrollviewtexture">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:text="Memorable"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:typeface="sans"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="(Swipe To Generate Password)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textSize="5pt"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In Eclipse it shows the background image no problem, but when I run in the emulator is doesn't display. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: clean ur project and try to run again

Comment: What is the directory in which the image is stored actually in: `drawable` or some of `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`?

Comment: might be a resolution problem with your screen.

Comment: I did use PNG. @BorisStrandjev It's stored in drawable-ldpi drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi. All three. what sort of resolution problem

Comment: Minimize eclipse, Just copy the images from relative folders, open eclipse and past  them in those folders.

Comment: make drawable folder and put inside the image. i hope now it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option about the problem is that you created you Emulator in such a way that the Android OS determines its screen as `xhdpi`. If an image is placed in `drawable` resource folder then Android will try to rescale it for the different resolutions. However if the image appears only in some of the resolution folders (lie `drawable-ldpi` etc) then the image will be served only in this resolutions.

Please, either create folder `drawable-xhdpi` and place the image also there, or create folder `drawable` and place the image there. It will be used for backup.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) about the image folders.

Comment: I tried adding both a drawable folder and then a drawable-xhdpi but with no difference.

Comment: Solved it. Removed the layout and re-added and it works. Keep the folder name "drawable"

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any error message?

Did you set the AVD to the appropriate settings that would actually use the image files you saved in your drawble folders?

Also try to clean the project and run again. Eclipse does not update these files regularly without explicitly cleaning the complete project.

Comment: No error codes, other than a warning about using NSQuickDrawView as it's outdated. I've tried cleaning it. What setting on the AVD might effect that?

Comment: Depending on the screen settings the system might take the different png files from the different resolution drawable folders

Answer (score 1):

i tried the layout  it works fine. You create a folder named as `drawable` similar to `drawable-hdpi`. Put your image inside the  `drawable` folder. It work fine.

Comment: tried that and it still doesn't appear in the AVD when running

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.. background would look fine on the preview but on running the app it just didn't show up. Worked once I used a lower def image.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html
Creating different folders with different resolutions of the same image allows your app to select the best for the device it's running on.

Answer (score -1):

I was encountering this problem because I was using a color from `?attr` called `colorControlActivated` in my xml drawable. Changing that to a hex code ( of the same color) that I defined in my `@colors file` solved my problem.